# Javascript - update var with simplified oneline if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Small question, I have a var in JS and I want to increment it as long as the current value is under 99, else it should be reset to zero.

### current simplified code

```
var age = 35;
age = ( age < 99) ? age+1 : 0;
```

Now, this is reasonably human readable. But what if my var would be `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]`
That would change my line to something like:

```
obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] = ( obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] < 99) ? obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]+1 : 0;
```

### The question

Is there a way to simplyfie this? Something like:

```
age = (< 99) ? ++ : 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do so is to create a function:

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  }
};

function increment(value, max) {
  // this do the same as your ternary operator
  return (value + 1) % max;
}

obj['a']['b'] = increment(obj['a']['b'], 100);

console.log(obj['a']['b']);

// THIS DOES NOT WORK (won't update obj):
var x = obj['a']['b'];
x = increment(x, 100);
console.log(obj['a']['b'], x);
```

Comment: Hmm, I like this. It's a recurring 'problem' and this is neat and readable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Store variable in to `temp` variable then do the operation:

Try this:

```
let age = obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape];
obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] = ( age < 99) ? (age + 1) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo `( % )` operator like this -

```js
var age = 95;
var limit = 100;

function incrementValue()
{
    age = (age+1) % limit;
    document.getElementById('number').value = age;
}

document.getElementById('number').value = age;
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="number" id="number"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]` to a variable and use it in the ternary operator

```js
var x=obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]
x= ( x< 99) ? x+1 : 0;
obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]=x;
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work, `x` is not a reference to `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]`

Comment: This does not work. `x` is coreferent with `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]`, but not synonymous to it; assigning to `x` does not modify `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]`. You need to leave one level unresolved.

Comment: I believe this would work with Java, but not with JS

Comment: It would not work with Java, either. You'd need a language with alias references, like C++ or PHP.

Comment: This won't work in any language if numbers are immutable (Javascript, Java, C#, etc.). You would need an explicit memory reference to that value (C or C++)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted it as one line, I think your solution might be the best way to solve it. Or you can either use a temporary variable or if else to get a shorter variable.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest you can get is either:

```
let y = obj[layer01][gridY][gridX], x = y[shape];
y[shape] = (x < 99) ? x + 1 : 0;
```

or the utterly unreadable

```
(x => x[shape] = x[shape] < 99 ? x[shape] + 1 : 0)(obj[layer01][gridY][gridX])
```

or even

```
((x, a) => x[a] = x[a] < 99 ? x[a] + 1 : 0)(obj[layer01][gridY][gridX], shape)
```

As I noted in comments to some other answers, you cannot just take a variable that references `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]`, since assigning to that variable will not have any impact on `obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]`. You need to preserve at least the level above the leaf in order to be able to assign to the leaf.

Anyway, unless you're golfing, you should not be afraid of adding an extra line. Readability is better than brevity. As noted by another answer, I'd prefer to make the logic explicit using the modulo operator:

```
obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] = (obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] + 1) % 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think this is a brilliant idea, I found the following solution:

```
obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] = function(x) { var i = parseInt(x); return i < 99 ? ++i : 0; }(obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]);
```

The big thing here is the parseInt calls - and the inline function made it a little simpler, but i would create a separate function and call it like this:

```
var myfn = function(x) { var i = parseInt(x); return i < 99 ? ++i : 0; };
obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape] = myfn(obj[layer01][gridY][gridX][shape]);
```

It can be re-used .. but it does not really answer your question - one line of code. The ternary operator is used for this - but yes it looks ugly.